# Trusted Online Catalog - SharePoint Required?

Tags: office-js

I have developed a few web add-in's for Excel. For local development, I've simply used a shared folder to host the manifest (xml) files. However, I'd like to centralize them by having the manifests on my website. If I upload the XML manifest to my website, and use the path as the "trusted catalog" in Excel trust settings, it does not recognize the manifests on my site. Perhaps I'm oversimplifying it, thinking it should work that way.

I notice it says SharePoint for catalog type. I do not have SharePoint. Is it possible to create the necessary files that MS Office Excel is looking for so that it recognizes my web directory as a "catalog", so that it may then see my XML manifest files?

Ultimately, I'd just like to have a universal location for the manifests to read from so they work if I move the document to another computer, or someone else uses it --without having to package the manifest with it, setup a new trusted folder and so on. I'm not looking to sell the add-in, or even want it to be public really, so that's why I've avoided the MS store option.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to centrally deploy an add-in, you have a couple of options:

1. [SharePoint catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog)
2. [Centralized Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment)

The SharePoint catalog is the older of the two but has the benefit of working regardless of where your hosting SharePoint.

Centralized Deployment however is far more powerful. It is included with Office 365 and, unlike SharePoint, requires very little configuration.

Without O365 or SharePoint, your options are limited to a network share or [publishing to AppSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-the-office-store) (aka the "Office Store").

Comment: I have to say, that's disappointing. I was curious if there was a way to use your own webserver as the "catalog" for XML Manifests. If perhaps the office product looked for a type of file you could recreate that told the software the web directory was a catalog. Seems that's not possible. It doesn't seem to make sense to flood AppSource with every add-in I ever create that would be meaningless to the outside world.

Comment: I understand. The best option by far is Centralized Deployment since this acts like a self-contained AppSource catalog for an organization. It's also the only option aside from AppSource that works across Windows, Mac, Web, etc..

Comment: What is SharePoint doing that my webserver camt? Can we hack this/mimic SharePoint. Its literally a txt file with urls in it. Any webserver should work, this wreaks of purposely blocking by MS